# Is it unprofessional to ask to be considered for a different [available] position during the interview process?

Tags: interviewing

There's a company I'd really like to work for that has 2 different positions open, one for a full-stack web developer, and one for a mobile developer. I had a really hard time deciding which one to apply for, and ended up applying to the mobile one.

I got far enough in the interview process that they've given me a mobile programming challenge to do, but I'm really regretting applying for the mobile position. I wish I had applied to the web one, because I'm much more experienced in web and like it better. I'm not even 100% sure why I decided on the mobile position in the first place. It seems silly to go through this entire process if I don't even feel excited about the position after all, but I'm still really excited about the other position.

Would it be a bad idea to send an email asking if they'd consider me for the web position instead? The company is small enough that I don't think they'd need to go through an entirely different department (during the phone interview they kept asking if I was applying for the web or mobile position), so I think it would be okay, I'm more worried that this would look unprofessional, and like I don't know my own ambitions and talents.

Answer (score 4):

Call up your contact at the company.  Explain to them that upon reflection you've decided that you'd rather stick to web development and ask how you can go about continuing to interview with them for that position.

They'll likely ask why.  Be honest and open about it and see where this leads you.  BTW, no, I would not consider this unprofessional.  As a manager, I'd respect someone coming to me about this before the interview got too far.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for a change in position when they have asked you to take a programming challenge may not reflect good on you. It may appear like you are afraid of the challenge now. 
I think you should hold on to your request for sometime and complete your mobile programming challenge first.

If you move further in the interview process, then you can politely ask if you can also apply or be-considered for other position. Since you mentioned it is likely within the same department, I would think there is a good chance they will consider your request. They also have verified your skills by now.

If you do not move further in the mobile role, then you certainly can ask to be considered or re-apply for other position because previous one did not work out.  Unless they declined you on basis of some skills which is needed for both the positions, they may reconsider you for other position again.

I think second scenario is relatively unlikely because before declining you for the mobile role, they may just ask themselves if you are better fit for any other open role. (Assuming a small company like you mentioned).

Of course there is lot of assumptions about employer behavior here which can be wrong in various ways. My basic suggestion is take the challenge either ways and then decide your next steps.